# flask service on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, json-rpc

I'm trying to figure out how to run a web service on heroku using flask and JSONRPC.
I would like to get to a point where, from my desktop I can do:

```
from flask_jsonrpc.proxy import ServiceProxy

service = ServiceProxy('http://<myapp>.heroku.com/api')
result = service.App.index()
print result
```

looking at heroku logs I can see :

```
2014-07-05T13:18:42.910030+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-07-05 13:18:42 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:21040 (2)
```

and trying using that port with :

```
service = ServiceProxy('http://<myapp>.heroku.com:21020/api')
```

still doesn't make it work (it seems hanging)

But when I run this through foreman, though, I can happy access it and seems working fine.

but when I try with the deployed application I get:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

This is the application (not much I know , but is just to see how heroku works)

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_jsonrpc import JSONRPC

app = Flask(__name__)

jsonrpc = JSONRPC(app, '/api', enable_web_browsable_api=True)

@jsonrpc.method('App.index')
def index():
    return u'Welcome to Flask JSON-RPC'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=port)
```

this is the content of my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn run:app -p $PORT
```

Am I missing something obvious here ? 
Cheers.

L.

p.S

accessing http://.heroku.com/api/browse
from within the through foreman and the deployed app, it seems working fine.

[edit]

**solved :**

yes I was missing something.... looking better a the log I noticed the host which was :

```
host=<myapp>.herokuapp.com
```

instead of 
    .heroku.com

Changing the address to the correct one, it all seems working fine.
http://.herokuapp.com/api

Answer (score 0):

All sorted , see original post.
Sorry for the noise.